# Dynamic URL redirect htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

First of all, I checked older questions on the topic but I can't get it to work still.

I basically want:

http://example.com/example/?test=3 to redirect to http://www.yahoo.com

I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /example/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^test=3$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^/example/index\.php$ http://www.yahoo.com [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah yeah, I forgot that I already declared rewrite base. So, it should have been:

`RewriteRule ^/index\.php$` instead of `RewriteRule ^/example/index\.php$`

Solved.

Comment: It shouldn't work. The URI-path checked in the rule does not have a leading slash (`^/index`) so it can't be add it to the regex for the comparison. I don't think it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines just below your RewriteBase line:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^test=3$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^example/(index\.php|)$ http://www.yahoo.com? [L,R=301,NC]
```

And comment out your 2 lines below Wordpress rules.